# Do multiple attacks get advantage for both attacks if the creature is under the effects of Faerie Fire?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, advantage-and-disadvantage

My bard's first action (if possible) in combat is to cast Faerie Fire. In our last D&D session, I was quite successful (for a change) and 5 of the six creatures in my 15 ft cube failed their saves and were marked for advantage.

The rules describe the the effects as "any attack roll against an affected creature or object has advantage if the attacker can see it..." We have a couple of characters in our group that have multiple attacks per round. I believe the advantage rules for multiple attacks state that the advantage is only on the first attack. Does the effect of Faerie Fire override this?

Comment: I think we need more information as to HOW a few of your characters have Multiple attacks.  If taking the 'Attack Action' with 'Extra Attack' ability (usually gained around level 5 for some classes) , then it's both.  Please elaborate so a given answer can properly address your situation.

Comment: I'll have to check but either from house rule or something else we've always played that when given advantage and you have multiple attacks the advantage is only for the first attack i.e. the duel wielding fighter.  I can try to find later and edit/delete this comment.

Comment: @nitsua60 because the vague 'multiple attacks per round' as Fogcutter phrased it could be from *Magic Missile* , *Cordon of Arrows* , secondary damage from a source like *Colossus Slayer* ; since he didn't specifically say, we are *assuming* he means what WE mean:  Attacks = anything involving an attack roll.  I just figured rephrasing might help give an answer specific to his situation.

Comment: To further clarify Airatome's comment, @Fogcutter, it's not just us that say "Attacks = anything involving an attack roll." That's directly from Mearls: "If there's ever any question whether something you're doing counts as an attack, the rule is simple: if you're making an attack roll, you're making an attack." (PHB p.194) So all of the examples Airatome lists above are *not* attacks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I can find nothing about Advantage that suggests it only affects one attack per round. I have looked in the Player's Handbook on pages 6 and 173, where the Advantage rules are described.

The only rule that's similar that I can find is:

> If multiple situations affect a roll and each one grants
>   advantage or imposes disadvantage on it, you don’t roll
>   more than one additional d20. If two favorable situations
>   grant advantage, for example, you still roll only one
>   additional d20.

Since you are rolling separate d20s for each attack, you benefit from Advantage on each attack, not just once per round.

In general though, D&D operates on a "specific trumps general" principle. Faerie Fire does not specify that it overrides any of the general Advantage rules, therefore it does not. However, there is no "Advantage on attacks once per round" rule.

Answer (score 20):

To start with, multiple attacks don't have a special rule that says advantage only applies to the first attack. As a result, Faerie Fire saying any attack roll gets advantage isn't changing or overriding any base rules.

But the answer ends up the same: yes, every attack roll against a target lit up by Faerie Fire gets advantage, exactly like the spell says, but not for the reason you were thinking.

Comment: There are a few "get advantage on next attack" situations though, which might be confusing the OP, and could be the subject of similar question. E.g. target hit with Guiding Bolt.